# How to subscribe to and see events from Hyperledger Composer transactions

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am running an NodeJS server with the following code to connect to the Hyperledger Runtime:

```
const BusinessNetworkConnection = require("composer-client")
  .BusinessNetworkConnection;
this.businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
this.CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME = "hlfv1";
this.businessNetworkIdentifier = "testNetwork";
this.businessNetworkConnection
  .connect(
    this.CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME,
    this.businessNetworkIdentifier,
    "admin",
    "adminpwd"
  )
  .then(result => {
    this.businessNetworkDefinition = result;
    console.log("BusinessNetworkConnection: ", result);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // Subscribe to events.
    this.businessNetworkConnection.on("events", events => {
      console.log("**********business event received**********", events);
    });
  })
  // and catch any exceptions that are triggered
  .catch(function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
```

I see data returned after the connection has been made in the `result` object and it is the correct network data that has been deployed.

However, when I submit transactions and made request VIA my generated REST APIs no events are seen by my server. In the Historian, I can see that events are emitted. Is there something else that I should be doing to see those events emitted by my transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried same kind of test and I could receive events. I compared my test code and yours, and I found following difference:

this.bizNetworkConnection.on('events'

this.bizNetworkConnection.on('event'

I hope it helps.